# SPARQL: unable to use FactForge endpoint

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib, graphdb

I am using `python` to run some `sparql` queries. I want to extract information from  [`http://factforge.net/sparql`](http://factforge.net/sparql)

```
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://factforge.net/sparql")
query = """
# F02: Big Cities in Eastern Europe

PREFIX onto: <http://www.ontotext.com/>
PREFIX gn: <http://www.geonames.org/ontology#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

SELECT * FROM onto:disable-sameAs
WHERE {
    SERVICE <http://factforge.net/sparql>{
    ?loc gn:parentFeature dbr:Eastern_Europe ; 
         gn:featureClass  gn:P;
         gn:featureCode gn:A.ADM2.
    ?loc dbo:populationTotal ?population ; dbo:country ?country .
    ?country a dbo:Country .
    }
    FILTER(?population > 300000 )
    ?country skos:prefLabel ?country_name . 

} ORDER BY ?country_name DESC(?population)

"""
sparql.setQuery(query)
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()
```

This query works on the [factforge](http://factforge.net/sparql) website but locally I receive the following error `EndPointNotFound: it was impossible to connect with the endpoint in that address, check if it is correct.`

Answer (score 3):

GraphDB exposes RDF4J-style API. This is exactly what is said on the [Help](http://factforge.net/webapi) page.

The SPARQL endpoint address should be `http://factforge.net/repositories/{repositoryID}`.

Unfortunately, it is impossible to determine which repository is used from SPARQL in GraphDB.

You could use F12 Developer Tools in your browser for this purpose. Or the [About](http://factforge.net/about) page says:

> Applications can access FactForge via SPARQL at
>   http://factforge.net/repositories/ff-news.
>   This is also the service address to be used for federated SPARQL queries.