# Connecting GATE gazzeetteer_lkb to geonames remote repository

Tags: sparql, rdf, gate, geonames, turtle-rdf

I am trying to configure `gazzetteer_lkb` with `geonames.com` remote repository so I can perform global location lookups.

I need help to correctly configure the `config.ttl` and `query.txt` files

`Config.ttl` needs to be a valid Turtle RDF format?

Also I am getting errors when loading the sample dictionary using below `config.ttl`:

```
# Gazetteer_LKB dictionary configuration file.
#
# %temp% will be automatically replaced with the TEMP folder for the current user
# %relpath% will be replaced with the path to the dictionary folder.
#
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.
@prefix rep: <http://www.openrdf.org/config/repository#>.
@prefix hr: <http://www.openrdf.org/config/repository/http#>.
@prefix lkbg: <http://www.ontotext.com/lkb_gazetteer#>.

# The dictionary will be loaded from a remote Sesame HTTP repository. 
# Its configuration follows. See the Sesame configuration for detals.
# http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/users/ch07.html#section-repository-config
[] a rep:Repository ;
   rep:repositoryImpl [
      rep:repositoryType "openrdf:HTTPRepository" ;

      # This URL is a public limitted SPARQL endpoint. All queries are truncated to 10000 results.
      hr:repositoryURL <http://factforge.net/sparql>

      # This URL points to the unlimitted password-protected factforge endpoint.
      # Ontotext partners can contact info@factforge.net to request credentials. 
      # Please include the SPARQL that you indend to run.
      # Set the credentials below.
      #hr:repositoryURL <http://factforge.net/repositories/owlim>


   ];
   rep:repositoryID "owlim" ;
   rdfs:label "FactForge" .

# The gazetteer-specific options follow.
lkbg:DictionaryConfiguration 
   # Whether the gazeetteer will be sensitive to case.
   # Possible values: caseinsensitive, casesensitive
   lkbg:caseSensitivity "caseinsensitive" ;

   #(optional) Authentication
   #If you are connecting to a repository guarded by HTTP basic authentication,
   #supply credentials as follows:
   #lkbg:username "<username>" ;
   #lkbg:password "<password>" ;

   # Whether the gazetteer will cache the dictionary after loading it from the data source.   
   # Put "enabled" to enable the cache, any other values will disable it.
   lkbg:caching "enabled" .

   # The cache will be automatically reloaded on initialization if the configuration have been    
   # modified since the last initialization. However, changes in the underlying datastore 
   # can't be detected and the cache will not be automatically reloaded in that case. 
   # Thus, if you expect changes in your datastore, disable the cache, or make use
   # of the modifications API.
```

Error message:

```
Aug 27, 2018 7:31:13 PM org.openrdf.http.client.HTTPClient getErrorInfo
WARNING: Server reports problem: Not Found (HTTP status 404)
Loading failed.
com.ontotext.kim.client.query.KIMQueryException: Error in repository connection.
```

Has anyone successfully connected geonames to a gate app?

Many thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47454145/7879193

Comment: I think `http://factforge.net/sparql` is a broken link. Try `http://factforge.net/repositories/ff-news` instead. See some details in the question page posted by @StanislavKralin